# What is maximum file size limit in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, clone, binaries

Currently, I cant clone the mercurial directory due to following error

```
Abort: stream ended unexpectedly.
```

We have few files that are larger than 10MB in size. These files are already uploaded on mercurial repository but we are getting error while doing a clone of that directory. We also have checked our internet connection which is not the issue. please guide what is the maximum size mercurial can transfer.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

We've had this issue when hosting the "master" repository on a shared host.

The hosting company had routines in place which would kill any processes using too much memory, and it seems hgweb loads most of the repository in memory during cloning. Thus if the timing was right, hgweb would get killed in the middle of the cloning operation, producing the error message you posted on the client.

We've moved our "master" repository to Bitbucket for now.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an abruptly aborted stream it's not any limitation that Mercurial is imposing -- that would come with a clear error message.  What server do you have hosting hgweb?  Are you using Apache or another http server?  Are you going over ssh?  This is more likely trouble at your network level than it is a Mercurial configuration issue -- and certainly it's not a fundamental Mercurial limitation.

Answer (score -1):

Generally the limits are in Gb area and defined by the operating system rather than mercurial (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HandlingLargeFiles).

However, you repository might have a hook configured to limit the binary file size. See for example https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2009-January/023322.html

So you need to check the configuration of your repository in `.hg/hgrc`

Comment: Can you please guide where to find this hook information. On hg server or on our local copy of repository. As checked in my local copy it has just the path info. And I don't have access to server.

Comment: I have checked on the server as well. It just has [web]
push_ssl = false

Comment: So it is neither that nor the mercurial itself. Sorry I cannot help further, but your question was about max file size for mercurial

Comment: Please learn the difference between Gb and GB.

Comment: To say that this was rude is to say nothing. As one can see from your comment, the difference between bits and bytes makes a fundamental difference for the correctness of the whole answer. But, yeah, I can see -- SO apparently does not provide any tools to suggest/make an edit, so one needs to fall back on insulting comments :) Good luck